# Is there an API \ command line \ other automation method to configure parental control on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, parental-controls

I'm looking for a method to automate the configuration of parental control on Windows 7

Is there an API \ command line \ other automation method to configure parental control on Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For controlling Parental Controls I have used the options in WMI. It is located in root\CIMV2\Applications\WindowsParentalControls. You can download the tool [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) to view WMI.

Otherwise here is more info on the API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338592.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous parental control tools out there. Without knowing a more clear specification on what exactly you would like to achieve I point you to Windows Live Family Safety which is included in [Microsoft Windows Live Essentials](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-essentials). Just download it (for free) and try it.